# traversing a tree from a list in python to do calculations?

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have this list:

```
new_tree = {'cues': 'glucose_tol',
  'directions': '<=',
  'thresholds': '122.5',
  'exits': 1.0,
  'children': [{'cues': True},
   {'cues': 'mass_index',
    'directions': '<=',
    'thresholds': '30.8',
    'exits': 1.0,
    'children': [{'cues': 'pedigree',
      'directions': '<=',
      'thresholds': '0.305',
      'exits': 1.0,
      'children': [{'cues': True},
       {'cues': 'diastolic_pb',
        'directions': '<=',
        'thresholds': '77.0',
        'exits': 1,
        'children': [{'cues': True}, 
        {'cues': 'insulin',
         'directions': '<=',
         'thresholds': '480',
         'exits': '0.5',
         'children': [{'cues': True}, {'cues': False}]}]}]}]}]}
```

and I want to get the path that these datapoints go in this tree list so that I can have the cues where they go and then do some calculations.

I have data points in a `df` (2 datapoints just for illustration):

```
print(df)

times_pregnant,glucose_tol,diastolic_pb,triceps,insulin,mass_index,pedigree,age,label
6,148,72,35,0,33.6,0.627,50,1
1,85,66,29,0,26.6,0.351,31,0
```

the first one will go glucose_tol, mass_index, pedigree, diastolic_pb and will be classified as True. How do I get these 4 cues from that list that this datapoint went through and save them for future calculations? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you want but maybe this helps? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a decision tree.

The way it works is that at each step you are either on a final decision state ('cues': True, or 'cues': false) or you need to make a decision.

To make the decision you need to get the field named in 'cues' from your dataframe, then using direction and threshold you form an condition. The first one is basically `if glucose_tol <= 122.5`. Each node should have 2 children I think the first one if for the true case and the second for the false (it should be obvious to you if you know the domain). You then pick the child based on your decision an continue.

Probably the easiest thing to do is to implement a recursive function. Once you have the function to evaluate the tree against a row of data you can add functionality to store what you want or what you think it's interesting.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Could you please try to write a pseudo-code for the recursive function you mentioned for python?